# Kotlin equivalent to Swift's #file, #line, and #function

Tags: java, android, swift, kotlin, logging

In Swift, I can use the following code to log a message, and I have access to all the relevant data I need:

```
class func log(type: LogType, message: String, fileName: String = #file, line: Int = #line, column: Int = #column, function: String = #function)
```

How can I do something similar in Android Java or Kotlin (preferable)?

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet but I ended up using the following code, it was exactly what I was after: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60785969/19493002)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Kotlin there isn't anything that can give you, for example, a line number so easily. However, on Android, in most of the times we use [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) as a logging 3rd party library, which is very convenient.

So, in Timber it can be achieved like this:

```
class LineNumberDebugTree : Timber.DebugTree() {
    override fun createStackElementTag(element: StackTraceElement): String? {
    return "(${element.fileName}:${element.lineNumber})#${element.methodName}"
}
```

`Timber.plant(LineNumberDebugTree())`

You can find additional info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689399/log-method-name-and-line-number-in-timber) thread.