# Timber - Problem with creating a custom Timber Debug Tree class

Tags: android, timber-android

I'm trying to create a custom `Debug Tree class` to get the same result as the following:

[image]

[image]

I have followed this Stackoverflow answer:

[Log method name and line number in Timber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689399/log-method-name-and-line-number-in-timber)

But using that answer gives me two problems:

1. Implementing the custom `Debug Tree` class does not log anything when I use more than one method.

```
public class MyDebugTree extends Timber.DebugTree {     
    @Override 
    protected String createStackElementTag(StackTraceElement element) {
        return String.format("(%s:%s)#%s",
            element.getFileName(),
            element.getLineNumber(),
            element.getMethodName());
    } 
}
```

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(new MyDebugTree);
        }
    }
}
```

The above causes it to not log at all.

If I use only `return element.getFileName();` it successfully logs that one error.

2. The second problem I'm having is that using a custom `DebugTree` class does not give me the same results as using `err.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()`.

```
 }, err -> {
     Timber.e("Method name: " + err);
     Timber.e("Method name: " + err.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());
}
```

[image]

The custom `Debug Tree` class does not display the name of the method I'm trying to log.

Why is it not logging when I use all three methods?

Also how can I get it to log like it would using

`err.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()`?

---

I'm using `'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing it right. I recreated your code in kotlin (*programming language should not matter*) and i was able to show my logs.

**MyDebugTree.kt**

```kotlin
class QueenlyDebugTree : Timber.DebugTree() {
    override fun createStackElementTag(element: StackTraceElement): String {
        return "(${element.fileName}:${element.lineNumber})#${element.methodName}"
    }
}
```

force log using an actual exception:

```kotlin
try {
    throw RuntimeException("Hello World")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Timber.e(e)
}
```

i got a log:
[image]

So, from what i saw from your code, its most probably because you have a compact logcat view. To update your logcat view, follow these steps:

**1. Make sure you have standard view selected**
[image]
[image]

**2. Configure standard view**

[image]

**3. Make sure Show tags is selected and tag column is at max(35)**
[image]